# How to use Valgrind and vera++ in windows

Tags: c++, qt, valgrind, vera++

I am looking for a memory leak detector in Qt whether static or not, like CppCheck.
Then i found Valgrind ( Valgrind memory analyzer remote ) and Vera++, Valgrind is integrated with Qt, Is it work fine for Windows?
I also got Vera++, an execute file, But i dont know how to use it. Could any one tell me how use these both?

Comment: There's no Valgrind supported version for Windows and the fact that uses Qt just means the UI toolkit might be recompiled on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valgrind is for Linux. A very good memory solution for the same tasks in Windows is [Dr. Memory](http://www.drmemory.org/). It does great job detecting memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks, Dr.Memory is really what i want

Comment: Unfortunetly Dr. Memory currently targets 32-bit applications only, any ideas on 64 bit?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use new feature of GCC: Memory Sanitizer.
It is much faster than Valgrind (smaller performance overhead) and it should also work in cases where Valgrind is failing (tracking stack variables). And since it is compiler feature it should also be available for Windows.

Here is a [good instruction how to use it with Qt](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2013/04/17/using-gccs-4-8-0-address-sanitizer-with-qt/).

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind is Linux-only.

So you need something different for Windows, I do not know of any free solution comparable to Valgrind.